# How to optimize my code for finding the count of all integral medians for all possible integral triangles with a <= b <= c <= 100000?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, time-complexity

I am doing the solution for this problem from [Euler Project Problem 513,  Integral median](https://projecteuler.net/problem=513):

> ABC is an integral sided triangle with sides a≤b≤c. mc is the median
>   connecting C and the midpoint of AB.  F(n) is the number of such
>   triangles with c≤n for which mc has integral length as well. F(10)=3
>   and F(50)=165.
>
> Find F(100000).

**Analyse:**

1. `a <= b <= c <= n == 100000`
2. ABC is a triangle so it should:  `abs(a-b) < c < a+b`
3. `Mc = sqrt(2 * a^2+ 2 * b^2 - c^2) / 2` [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_%28geometry%29)
4. `Mc` is integer so `2 * a^2+ 2 * b^2 - c^2` should be a perfect square and divisible by 4.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 100000
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

void main(){
    unsigned long int count = 0;
    unsigned long int a,b,c;
    double mc;

    for (a = 1; a <= N; a++) {
        printf("%lu\n", a);
        for (b = a; b <= N; b++)
            for (c = MAX(b, abs(b-a)); c <=N && c < a+b; c++){
                mc = sqrt(2 *a *a + 2 * b * b - c * c)/2.0;
                if (mc-(unsigned long)mc == 0)
                    count++;
            }
    }
     printf("\ncpt == %lu\n", count);

}
```

**Issues:**

It works fine for small `n` but the complexity of the solution is too high, I assume it is `O(n^3)`(am I wrong?) which will take days for `n = 100000`.

How could I improve this whether with a mathematical or algorithmic way?

**Updates**

I got those suggestions:

- Calculating power of `a` outside the `b`/`c` loops and power of `b` outside `c` loop. This improved slightly the performance.
- `c` cannot be odd. then `a` and `b` must have same parity. This improved the performance 4 times.
- Using threads to divide the work on many cores. It may improve by a factor close to number of cores.
- A mathematical solution posted in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254318/combinatorics-integer-sided-triangles-with-integer-median). It claims `O(N^5/2)` for a basic solution and can achieve `O(N^2)` by using `O(N^2)` of memory. I didn't test it yet.

Comment: For starters, you could calculate `2 *a *a` before the `b` loop, and `2 *a *a + 2 * b * b` before the `c` loop.

Comment: From #4, `c` cannot be odd. then `a` and `b` must have same parity. Not a full solution, but should give you a factor of 4 improvement.

Comment: Why isn't it `for (c=b; c<=N; c++)` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am trying your first suggestion. for `for (c=b; c<=N; c++)`, I am try to limit by both `b <= c <= N` and `abs(a-b) < c < a+b` (triangle condition)

Comment: Related question on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254318/combinatorics-integer-sided-triangles-with-integer-median), this question is related to a [new problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=513) of Project Euler.

Comment: @bigOTHER sorry yes of course, `c <= a+b`, so calculate the *min* of `a+b` and `N` before the `c` loop begins.

Comment: @SleuthEye Thanks,  rapidity increased by 4

Comment: bigOTHER, you should edit your question to provide proper attribution to Project Euler as the source of the problem, and link to it.

Comment: You may get a small boost be re-ordering your inner for loop if c < a+b happens more often than c <= N - which I would assume is the case.

Comment: Why not change your loop to loop over b, a, and mc? Since those are smaller values, you have fewer values to explore.  Your inmost mc loop can stop as soon as 2mc^2 - 2a^2 - 2b^2 > n^2.  This way as a + b approaches n, the number of possible values for mc becomes very small, which I suspect will improve your scaling considerably (although I haven't either tried it or worked out the scaling).

Comment: @DavidRoundy Good idea, I will work on it.

Comment: You should parallelize. This should give you an improvement by a factor close to the number of processor available.

Comment: You can simplify the equation to 4(mc^2+(c/2)^2) = 2(a^2+b^2).

Comment: @DouglasZare I don't get for what I use the equation `4(mc^2+(c/2)^2) = 2(a^2+b^2)`?

Comment: If you have an equation f(a,b,c,mc)=0, this suggests looping over all possible values of a, b, c, and mc, testing whether you get 0, Theta(n^4), or maybe looping over 3 values, counting how many roots there are for the 4th variable, Theta(n^3). That's not good enough here. If you can break up the equation into f(a,b)=g(c,mc), this suggests looping over the possibilities for the left variables to produce an array of possible left hand sides, then looping over the possibilities for the right hand variables to produce an array of possible right hand sides. These loops take Theta(n^2) steps.

Comment: Why are you taking the product of the left and right? That throws out the advantage you get from being able to separate the variables. To find the quadruples (a,b,c,mc) satisfying the equation, you are going back to looping over all Theta(n^4) quadruples. That is not what I said to do at all. Please don't state that it was my algorithm. I said to loop over the values taken by the left hand side, the (mc,c/2) pairs, looking up the key in the dictionary for the right hand side.

Comment: @DouglasZare Sorry for any misunderstanding , I wanted only to show you what I implemented.

Comment: Something which would remove the c loop immediately is to note that c and mc satisfy a Pell equation. These equations can be solved iteratively (I don't have an algorithm though...) and the solutions grow exponentially. If you manage to implement this it would be just like you would eliminate the c loop. That would make the problem like O(n^2) which is good enough and way better than O(n^3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a Project Euler problem, you are supposed to be able to do it in about a minute of computing time on a modern computer. They don't always stick to that, but it indicates that a running time of `k*n^2` or `k*n^2*log(n)` is probably fine if the constant isn't too bad, but probably not `k*n^2.5` or `k*n^3`.

As SleuthEye commented, the side c must be even or else the inside of the square root would have to be odd, so taking the square root and dividing by 2 could not make an integer.

You can simplify the equation to `4(mc^2+(c/2)^2) = 2(a^2+b^2)`.

Here is one approach: Create two dictionaries, left and right. For each, let the keys be possible values of that side of the equation, and let the values be a list of the pairs `(mc,c/2)` or `(a,b)` which produce the key. For the right dictionary, we only need to consider where `a` and `b` have the same parity, and where `1<=a<=b<=n`. For the left, we only need to consider `1<=c/2<=n/2` and `1<=mc<=sqrt(3)/2 n` since `4mc^2 = 2a^2+2b^2-c^2 <= 3b^2 <=3n^2`.

Then go through the possible keys, and compare the elements of the values from each dictionary, finding the number of compatible `((mc,c/2),(a,b))` pairs where `b <= c < a+b`. This inner step is not constant time, but the maximum and average lengths of the lists are not too long. The ways to write n as a sum of two squares roughly correspond (up to units) to the ways to factor n in the Gaussian integers, and just as the largest [number of factors of an integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate) does not grow too rapidly, the same is true in the Gaussian integers. This step takes `O(n^epsilon)` time for any `epsilon>0`. So, the total running time is `O(n^(2+epsilon))` for any `epsilon>0`.

In practice, if you run out of memory, you can construct partial dictionaries where the keys are restricted to be in particular ranges. This parallelizes well, too.

Comment: I implemented your proposition in Python. It didn't work for small `n` until i ignored the assumption  that `mc <= c/2`, I put `mc <= n`.  what's  `LHS`? For bigger n, it takes lot of time more then my original solution. I assume creating `left` and `right` is O(n^2) each and going through all possible pairs to take `O(n^4)`??:  `for x in product(right(), left())`. I will publish the code in my question.

Comment: LHS means Left Hand Side, the left hand side of `4(mc^2+(c/2)^2)=2(a^2+b^2)`, but I did make a mistake there, dropping a factor of 2, so you are right that you have to consider pairs with `mc>c/2` so the correct upper bound is not `c/2`. You can slightly improve `mc<=n` to `mc<sqrt(3)/2 n` since `4mc^2=2a^2+2b^2-c^2<= 3b^2<=3n^2`. Creating each dictionary takes about `n^2` steps. That's `2n^2` together not `n^4` together because you don't need to make `n^2` copies of the second dictionary, just one. After you make both dictionaries, you loop through the keys of one dictionary once.

Comment: I meant combining values from `left` and `right` to check compatible pairs is taking `O(n ^ 4)`. I published the code, check if it's how you meant it to be. Exactly the line `for x in product(right(), left())`.

Comment: Why are you taking the product of the left and right? That is not what I said to do.

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand you so, how to do instead?

Comment: Here is a simpler example. Suppose you were trying to count quadruples so that r+s^2=t^3+u^4. You could make a list of possible values of r+s^2, and how often they occur. You could do the same with the right hand side. Then for each possible value of the left hand side, you look up how often it occurs on the left and on the right and multiply those. That takes roughly quadratic time, the amount of time to create the dictionaries. It is not the same thing as taking the product of everything, which produces an n^4 size object as an intermediate step.

Comment: I made another implementation, very quick but I got  `MemoryError` while buliding `(a,b)` pairs dictionary with `a = 454`

Comment: I mentioned the possibility of running out of memory and how you can get around that. See the last paragraph.

Comment: Could you elaborate about that part because it is not clear to me.

Comment: Instead of filling the entire dictionaries, only create a dictionaries for keys in a limited range. Loop over the pieces of the range. So, the whole dictionary with keys from 2 through 10^10 is taking too much memory. Instead, pick a subrange, something smaller, that will fit in your memory, like 2 through 10^6. Generate only the key-value pairs with keys in this range. Then move to 10^6+1 through 2x10^6. Then 2x10^6+1 through 3x10^6 etc. Each piece will fit into memory. It won't take significantly more time if you set the loop limits so that you don't generate keys outside this range.

Comment: By the way, according to the solution forum, several people used essentially this approach to solve the problem, but it did take 1-2 orders of magnitude more computing power than one processor-minute. There were a couple of more complicated ideas that produced faster solutions, as well as a couple of people who admitted to using a brute-force search over days.

Comment: I used a range of `1e8` that needs about `1.6 GB`,  and I am letting it  go through it .